# How do you make Skylanders easier to play?

Tags: skylanders

Are there any cheats for the Skylanders Spyro's Adventure, Skylanders Giants, or Skylanders Swap-Force?

Answer (score 1):

There are no know cheats but you can drop the skill level down to Easy.  My 4 year old son was able to complete Giants on this difficulty, so you'll probably not need any cheats to beat it.

You might want an FAQ to help you find some of the more obscure hats, though...

http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/666534-skylanders-giants/faqs/67173

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there will be a difficulty setting in a settings menu. If not, it may not get any easier.